# Android stop CountDown

Tags: android, widget, countdown

I have a widget that display a countdown. For to do this I use the class CountDownTimer but the problem is that often the countdown is stopped ! I think because android automatically stop the thread because the countdownc during many houres. HOw can resolve this problem? Thanks

```
public class TempoIndietro extends CountDownTimer{
     AppWidgetManager manager;
     ComponentName thisWidget;

    public TempoIndietro(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, widget.class); 
        manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);  
        remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widgett);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, context.getResources().getString(R.string.onair_widget_countdown));
        manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                SimpleTimeFormat tf = new SimpleTimeFormat("$dd$ : $HH$: $mm$: $ss$");    
                String risultato = tf.format(millisUntilFinished); // arg0 tempo
                remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.textView2, risultato);
                manager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteView);
            };
        }
```

Comment: How are you supposed to help you with seeing your code

Comment: i have add a countdown code into answer

Comment: When do the onTick() executed? Or in other words when do update the widget? In every minute?

Answer (score 0):

remember the start time of your timer and calculate the difference from that time.

you can use the local storage for this.

best to call it in onStop() and onResume() inside your Activity.

Save:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myappname", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putLong("varname", startDate.getTime());
editor.commit();
```

Retrieve:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("myappname", 0);
Long millis = settings.getLong("varname", null);
Date startDate = new Date(millis);
```

Comment: It is a widget the problem is that this countdown can during many hours or days and android kill the countdown thread....